# Can a player enter the top 16 for the following season if he wins a world championship?

Tags: rules, snooker

Due to Ronnie O'Sullivan's absence in almost all snooker tournaments through the 2012-2013 season, he dropped out the top 16 for the next season. But since he won the 2013 World Championship, will he be given permission to enter the top 16 for the 2013-2014 season?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, he will not be a in the "Top 16 list", however if he decides to take place in any tournament on the [World Snooker Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Snooker_Tour) he would not need to play a qualifikation.

In 2005 Shaun Murphy won the World Championship and he qualified automatically for every tournament in the next season as the number two seed (and number one seed for the 2006 World Championship)

Comment: It's worth noting that Ian McCulloch, the actual Nr. 16, effectively lost this ranking and had to play another qualifer round instead for that year.